Row-wise dot product in Polars
I have a dataframe with two columns values and weights of list[i64] dtype, and I'd like to perform row-wise dot product of the two.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'values': [[0], [0, 2], [0, 2, 4], [2, 4, 0], [4, 0, 8]],
    'weights': [[3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
})

There's one way that worked, which is first putting values and weights into a struct and then do .map_elements on each row:
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(['values', 'weights'])
    .map_elements(
        lambda x: np.dot(x['values'], x['weights']), return_dtype=pl.Float64
    ).alias('dot')
)

But as the documentation points out, map_elements is in general much slower than native polars expressions, so I was trying to implement in native expressions.
I tried the following:
df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list('values', 'weights').alias('combined'),
    pl.concat_list('values', 'weights').list.eval(pl.element().slice(0, pl.len() // 2)).alias('values1'),
    pl.concat_list('values', 'weights').list.eval(pl.element().slice(pl.len() // 2, pl.len() // 2)).alias('values2'),
    pl.concat_list('values', 'weights').list.eval(
        pl.element().slice(0, pl.len() // 2).dot(pl.element().slice(pl.len() // 2, pl.len() // 2))
    ).list.first().alias('dot'),
    pl.concat_list('values', 'weights').list.eval(
        pl.element().slice(0, pl.len() // 2) + pl.element().slice(pl.len() // 2, pl.len() // 2)
    ).alias('sum'),
)

I was expecting the dot column to be [0, 6, 16, 10, 28], but it turns out to be the following.
shape: (5, 7)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ values    ┆ weights   ┆ combined    ┆ values1   ┆ values2   ┆ dot ┆ sum        │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]  │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ [0]       ┆ [3]       ┆ [0, 3]      ┆ [0]       ┆ [3]       ┆ 0   ┆ [0]        │
│ [0, 2]    ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ [0, 2, … 3] ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ 4   ┆ [0, 4]     │
│ [0, 2, 4] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [0, 2, … 3] ┆ [0, 2, 4] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 20  ┆ [0, 4, 8]  │
│ [2, 4, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [2, 4, … 3] ┆ [2, 4, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 20  ┆ [4, 8, 0]  │
│ [4, 0, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [4, 0, … 3] ┆ [4, 0, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 80  ┆ [8, 0, 16] │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────┴────────────┘

Note that even the sum isn't what I expect it to be. The first slice seems to be adding itself instead of the second slice
Am I doing anything wrong? What's the best way to perform row-wise dot product in Polars?

Fwiw, here's one way to do row-wise dot product:
    pl.all().exclude('index'),
    (pl.col('values').explode() * pl.col('weights').explode()).sum().over('index').alias('dot')
)```

Not sure if it's the best way in the latest Polars version (1.0.0).

The above method (with explode) uses quite a lot of memory.

updated. With current version 1.10.0 arithmetic operations between lists are supported:
df.with_columns(
    dot = (pl.col.values * pl.col.weights).list.sum()
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ values    ┆ weights   ┆ dot │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ [0]       ┆ [3]       ┆ 0   │
│ [0, 2]    ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ 6   │
│ [0, 2, 4] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 16  │
│ [2, 4, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 10  │
│ [4, 0, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 28  │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────┘

oudated. Unfortunately, polars doesn't have dot product method for lists yet and list.eval() is somehow limited.
One possible solution without using explode() could be

.concat_list() to combine 2 lists into one.
list.eval().
.shift() to get a value from the second list.

df.with_columns(
    dot= pl.concat_list(pl.all()).list.eval(
        (pl.element() * pl.element().shift(pl.element().len() // 2)).sum()
    ).list.first()
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ values    ┆ weights   ┆ dot │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ [0]       ┆ [3]       ┆ 0   │
│ [0, 2]    ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ 6   │
│ [0, 2, 4] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 16  │
│ [2, 4, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 10  │
│ [4, 0, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 28  │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────┘

But I think performance might not be the best.
Another way of doing it could be using of DuckDB integration with Polars and list_dot_product function:
duckdb.sql("""
    select
        values, weights,
        cast(list_dot_product(values, weights) as int) as dot
    from df
""")

┌───────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│  values   │  weights  │  dot  │
│  int32[]  │  int32[]  │ int32 │
├───────────┼───────────┼───────┤
│ [6, 7, 3] │ [8, 3, 9] │    96 │
│ [5, 3, 3] │ [5, 3, 6] │    52 │
│ [4, 0, 5] │ [9, 7, 0] │    36 │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────┘


Thanks @Roman Pekar for your answer! I understand how your polars implementation works. But I still wonder why my pl.element().slice(0, pl.len() // 2).dot(pl.element().slice(pl.len() // 2, pl.len() // 2 doesn't. You see that without the dot operation, values1 and values2 returned what I expected, but somehow the dot operation is only performed on the first slice itself...

The above seems to be a bug of Polars. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17370
